# Update an object record if the user abort an apex job

Tags: apex

I have a scenario where I want to update an object record whenever a job is aborted manually. There is always a single record for this object and we are using this object to store the credentials of a third party application.

Comment: What type of job are you talking about? Please provide more details on what you've tried so far, why it didn't work, what features you are using, etc.

Comment: We are executing a batch class from a button on a lightning component and after executing the batch we are updating a field (boolean) on a custom object record in the finish method, we are again updating the value for this field. In the meantime, before the batch reached the finish if someone manually aborted the batch class, the field is not updating. is it possible to run custom apex code if a batch class get aborted?

Comment: how and why are users aborting the batch?

Comment: The user is aborting the job from Salesforce UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a visualforce page that allows the users to cancel the job using System.abortJob(). The visualforce page can then take care of populating the field in the custom object, based on the job id.